# Transparent gif images do not upload after rotation

Tags: php

I am working on a script that rotates images on upload. All images load up fine except `transparent gif images`. Once rotated they do not show up in the upload folder. I am thinking the issue is somewhere here:

```
......

$allowTypes = array('image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif');

......

if(!empty($rotation)){ 
                switch($fileType){ 
                    case 'image/png': 
                        $source = imagecreatefrompng($fileTemp); 
                        break; 
                    case 'image/gif': 
                        $source = imagecreatefromgif($fileTemp); 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTemp); 
                } 
                $imageRotate = imagerotate($source, $rotation, 0); 

                switch($fileType){ 
                    case 'image/png': 
                        $upload = imagepng($imageRotate, $filePath); 
                        break; 
                    case 'image/gif': 
                        $upload = imagegif($imageRotate, $filePath); 
                        break; 
                    default: 
                        $upload = imagejpeg($imageRotate, $filePath); 
                } 
}
```

.....

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you tested first to see what `$fileType` contains when you are uploading a gif? `echo $fileType;` Also have you checked the value of `$source` to make sure its not false (as in the `imagecreatefromgif` function did not error)?

Comment: Also, do you by chance have Imagick installed with your php? That set of tools is immensely helpful and robust.

Comment: @IncredibleHat with and without rotation `$fileType` echos `image/gif`. When I echo `$source` it show nothing (with or without rotation). Where can check what it's set to?

Comment: @IncredibleHat no I do not have Imagick installed. It's just a small custom script I've been working on. If I can fix this one particular issue I'll be happy with what I've got.

Comment: Echoing `$source` and getting nothing, means its `false`... which means, it failed. Generally means the file you passed it, was not found. Curious though, since you say the other functions DO work using `$fileTemp`... hm.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Just for fun of it I changed `$source = imagecreatefromgif($fileTemp);` to `$source = imagecreatefrompng($fileTemp);` and now transparent gifs upload fine but regular gifs do not. Seems like it's treating transparent gif as png.